# Bayesian CI - isn't it by definition a bootstrapped or robust enough confidence interval? or should it be optimized?

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, sampling, inference, markov-chain-montecarlo

As the title said, I've been wondering about bayesian methods, particularly MCMC, which seems to rely on sampling of the sample via chained iterations. Do we need an optimized/robust CI when running brms in r or does the CI by definition is already robust enough since it's a resultant from a resampling process?